# C++ Pointer Comparison

Tags: c++, pointers

How pointers are compared in C++?

The last line in the following code shows that values of `b` and `c` are different. However, `b==c` returns true.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
struct C : A, B { };

int main() {
    auto c = new C();
    B* b = static_cast<B*>(c);
    A* a = static_cast<A*>(c);
    a->a = 1;
    b->b = 2;
    std::cout << c->a << c->b <<"\n";
    std::cout << (a==c) << (b==c) << "\n";
    std::cout << (long)a << "\n" << (long)b << "\n" << (long)c <<"\n";
}
```

A sample output that I received using GCC and Clang:

```
12
11
34073632
34073636
34073632
```

Comment: Hint: `(b==c)` basically does `b == static_cast<B*>(c)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried `((void*)b==(void*)c)` and it did in fact returned `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cast pointers to long, cast them to intptr_t.

```cpp
    std::cout << (intptr_t)a << "\n" << (intptr_t)b << "\n" << (intptr_t)c <<"\n";
```

Anyhow, see this definition:

```cpp
struct C : A, B { };
```

in memory that would look like:

```
{
  A; [sizeof int]
  B; [sizeof int]
}
```

Since A and B are both base classes of C, when you do this:

```cpp
    A* a = static_cast<A*>(c);
```

You get a pointer to  the first 4 bytes of C. When you do this:

```cpp
    B* b = static_cast<B*>(c);
```

You get a pointer to the last 4 bytes of C, hence the difference. A pointer to type C will always implicitly cast the pointer this way.

Comment: Re: “ will always implicitly cast” — there are no implicit casts. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The proper term here is “implicit conversion “.